# How can I change page title in node with some options?

Tags: 8, nodes

how can I change page title drupal 8 in node with some options?
I want change my title on "test" if node have field "field_section" is "dogs".
Just in this page I want showing in "field--node--title.html.twig" 'test'.

I tried 
`function test_theme_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {

if($variables['field_name']=='title'){ 
   $variables['items']['changetitle']=true;
      // kint($variables);
   }
}`

But I don't know how to search from preprocess field other paramters other fields like my field in node 'field_section'.

I want mix in preproccesing_field 'if field_section have value 'dogs' then showing page_title is 'test'.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix all the things with 
RouteSubscriberBase
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones...

...

```
/** @var Route $entityUserEditForm */
$entityUserEditFormRoute = $collection->get('entity.user.edit_form');

// Change default user details entity form and title.
if ($entityUserEditFormRoute) {
  $entityUserEditFormRoute->setDefaults([
    '_entity_form' => 'user.complete_registration_form',
    '_title' => 'Complete Registration Form',
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Taggart. Because this has put me on the right track, it could help other people. Tutorial here: https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/change-page-title-user-edit-form-drupal-8-routesubscriber.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you don't want to do this in the node template? The following is pseudo code, but you could do something like this:

```
{% if content.field_section == 'dogs' %}
  CHANGED TITLE
{% else %}
  {{ label }}
{% endif %}
```